# Get value of textbox AFTER setting it via AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code which takes a value from text box id `fileno` and uses it to build a URL for AJAX call. The result of the AJAX call is then used to populate another textbox `filename`.

```
$('#loadbtn').click(function() {
   var url = 'loadfile.php?fn=' + $('#fileno').val();

   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {              
   $('#filename').val(data[0]['NameFile']).prop("disabled", true);
});
```

This works as intended, however I then want to perform a second AJAX call *using the value of `filename`*.

Assigning `$('#filename').val()` to a variable, or appending it to a URL string does not work. It says undefined, even though the textbox is populated on the page.

Comment: Please update your code to show how are you trying to make the 2nd ajax call using `$('#filename').val()`?

Comment: Can you make sure that the AJAX request is received? It also appears you are setting the value of #filename instead of reading it

Comment: @palaѕн My issue is that `console.log($('#filename').val());` returns nothing. However I just noticed that if I click #loadbtn a *second* time it is able to read the value. Why would that be?

I will update to show second AJAX call anyway

Comment: It's not super-clear what the issue is. If you have the filename then make the call--but if you're trying to do that *outside* of the callback you're running into normal async programming timing.

Comment: @DaveNewton the issue is: the ajax call works and populates the #filename textbox with the data, however I then cannot read the value of it using $('#filename').val()

Comment: *WHEN* are you trying to read the value of it? And why aren't you just making the second call in the first call's callback?

Answer (score 0):

What the commenters are trying to tell you is that the example code provided doesn't show how the value is being accessed. This is a (very common perceptual) problem when starting to work with asynchronous requests (e.g., `$.ajax, $.get, $.post, $.getJSON`, etc. in jQuery), since the data is not immediately available, but will be later on callback to the given handler once the request has been resolved. The code example is also not valid Javascript.

```
$('#loadbtn').click(function() {
    let url = 'loadfile.php?fn=' + $('#fileno').val();

    $.getJSON(url, function callback(data) {              
        $('#filename').val(data[0]['NameFile']).prop("disabled", true);

        // You now have $('#filename').val() to access, or data[0]['NameFile']
        console.log('Filename loaded', $('#filename').val())
    });

    // You DO NOT have $('#filename').val() to access, since this code is synchronous
    console.log('Filename will not be loaded', $('#filename').val())
});
```